# How to create docker base image from Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I am beginner in Docker and i need to implement docker in AWS and i want to create my own images. From the docker docs, i followed the process to create a Dockerfile. My question is how to create a base image using amazon linux ami?

I have a amazon linux machine in aws and i have done some security restriction done in that instance. I want this instance to be a base image for my docker and i want to create other docker images from this base image with all the security restrictions. How can i accomplish this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/amazon_linux_container_image.html .. is this the way to use amazon linux as base image ?

Comment: Yes the link which you gave is the correct way to use amazon linux as base image.

Comment: @Techiee thanks you :)

Comment: You are welcome bro :)

Comment: You have pretty good timing. Amazon just released that docker image four days ago: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-linux-container-image-for-cloud-and-on-premises-workloads/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AmazonWebServicesBlog+%28Amazon+Web+Services+Blog%29

Comment: @Paulpro thats preety cool :)

Comment: @Paulpro You should probably post that as the answer, that's more accurate than the one answer available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only application compatibility, you can try centos image which amazon Linux is based on:

```
FROM centos

.....
```

Regards